# How do I make the hover background color fill the height of the link?

Tags: html, css, hover

How do I make the hover `background-color` fill the entire height of the navigation bar plus the padding of the text instead of only the text.

I want to make it look like this.

[image: navigation bar]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onestaryx/cRjF4)

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please refer to this fiddle for my failed example. http://jsfiddle.net/onestaryx/cRjF4/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. I've created a jsfiddle for you. Its working good:

http://jsfiddle.net/cRjF4/3/

Updated CSS:

```
<style>
.fa {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.navbar-height {
    height: 65px;
}

.clearboth {
    clear: both;
}

/* workbar styles */

.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: 67px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.workbar {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffe6e6;
}

.worknav {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.worknav> li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
}

.worknav> li:hover a {
    color: yellow;
}

.worknav>li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.worknav > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

.centered {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.worktop {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Post the changed code as well, link answers may disappear and posting the code gives a better reference for people.

Comment: thank you! I also made an attempt to clean up my fiddle code to only keep the relevant parts for this example. http://jsfiddle.net/onestaryx/cRjF4/22/

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to colour both the padding and the text try something like:

```
a:hover{
background-color:yellow;
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do Anchor link css as

```
.worknav > li > a {    
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #666;
    line-height:65px;



}
```

Check on http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/cRjF4/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying padding on anchor tag. Remove height on ul and li tag and instead of height just apply padding on anchor. And also apply background-color on anchor.

It will work i think. If I am right then let me know i'll share some code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The main solution idea is line-height css property. If the background height and font-size's line-height the same then the background colour will cover the full height.