# How do I make my link hover background fill the entire background?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple navigation menu using a ul, but when you hover over it, the background color will not change the entire background. I think it may have to do with my `padding` elements. How do I fix this?

Here is a Fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/b8js8zkq/

I have looked at [How do I make the hover background color fill the height of the link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284220/how-do-i-make-the-hover-background-color-fill-the-height-of-the-link) and did not find a good answer there, so please don't mark this as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you have `margin` and `padding` on both `<h3>` and `<li>`. So remove them and add them as `padding` to the `<a>` tag. And you are done!

The `padding` and `margin` of each `15px` constitute `30px` of total `padding` to `<a>`. That's what I have done below:

```css
.header li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
ul h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.header a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/19r4a4ft/**

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend changing your css from this

```
.header a:hover{
  background-color: #f3e5d8;
}
```

to this

```
.header li:hover{
  background-color: #f3e5d8;
}
```

This will make it so any list item within your header class will change its background colour when hovered.

Comment: Not really a hack job, this is the way the majority of websites navigation bars work. This way anything within the header list will change on hover.

Comment: I know Ben... That's not right, right? We need to fix the problem, not patch it. I used to do it before but now I try to find the root cause and fix it rather than patch it. If you agree with me... `:D`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/b8js8zkq/1/

Fixed fiddle.

You remove the padding on both `<h3>` and `<li>`, and add that same padding to the `<a>`-tag.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/b8js8zkq/2/)

Old

```
 .header a:hover {
  background-color: #f3e5d8;
}
```

New

```
.header li:hover {
   background-color: #f3e5d8;
}
```

You want to change the color of the li element rather than just the a tag